# What happens to the Soyuz boosters that land in the Kazakhstan desert?

Tags: booster, recovery, soyuz-launcher

The video below mentions that Soyuz boosters consistently land a certain distance away from the Baikonur Cosmodrome, in deserted areas. What happens to those boosters? I'd sure like to have an interesting chunk of booster...

This article from [russianspaceweb.com](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/baikonur_downrange.html) mentions there used to be recovery, but that has stopped. [This thread](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/17495-Soyuz-Debris) on the Kerbal Space Program forum says 'rocket part hunters' harvest the scrap and sell it in China. (If so, they are missing a significant hobbyist market opportunity, I think...) Does anyone know more?

Comment: The Jawas drive around in their sand crawlers harvesting the engines and scrap metal. They then sell them to moisture farmers.

Comment: Those boosters land in the Altai region of Russia, which is to the northeast of Kazakhstan - _not_ in Kazakhstan itself.

Comment: I really wonder whether there are ever any surviving interesting bits.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Local scrap metal dealers collect and recycle them. See [this link](http://www.eurasianet.org/departments/culture/articles/eav041902.shtml) for some more information.

[image: eurasianet.org 1]
[image: eurasianet.org 2]
[image: eurasianet.org 3]

Comment: The middle one landed awfully near to houses. Can you get an app to tell you when not you use those walking tracks?